# Hexadecimal color codes grep regex in makefile

Tags: grep, regular-expression, colors, numeric-data

So I have a text file containing valid and invalid hexadecimal color codes. I want to be able to filter out the invalid codes and print just the valid ones. For a code to be valid it must have a hash symbol, be 6 or 8 characters long after the the hash and letters must be A-F. My grep command below, is stored in a makefile and everytime I try to run the file, it give me an error which you can see below.

Command:

```
grep -ivE '^#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{8})$' colours.txt
```

Error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'run-task-1' failed
make: *** [run-task-1] Error 2
```

Codes:

```
#b293a6
#ead58f
#a69d36a2
#067806
#afe6e
#7f0bf7ef
#dd85
#042847421
#1a283af
```

Output wanted:

```
#b293a6
#ead58f
#a69d36a2
#067806
#7f0bf7ef
```

Comment: use `[[:xdigit:]]` instead of `[a-f0-9]` -- I think it's more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `grep -ivE '^#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{8})$' colours.txt`

To get this to be what `make` passes to `sh`, you need to prevent `make` from recognizing `$` as a metacharacter and attempting to substitute a `make` variable.

Simply use `$$`.